# Trace32 Snooper.List data only in hex

Tags: trace32

I'm using trace32 SNOOP.List, after recording a variable with snooper.state. However, in list I can only see data in hexadecimal format. Is there a way to see that data in other formats, like float32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know: For memory there's only the option to display Hex, Decimal, Binary or Ascii, e.g.

```
SNOOPer.List Default %Binary Data %Decimal Data %Hex Data
```

If you have symbols loaded you can display the variables formatted as their type:

```
SNOOPer.List DEFault Var
```

And theres the option to draw them:

```
SNOOPer.DRAW.Var %DEFault <variable>
```

Comment: SNOOPer.List.Var is the right idea I think. However there is no command SNOOPer.List.Var, but TRACE32 accepts sometimes a dot instead of a blank for backward compatibility. The correct command is `SNOOPer.List Var`. (After SNOOPer.List you can specify items you like to see. "Var" in this case.) If you want to see all the other stuff you normally see in SNOOPer.List use command `SNOOPer.List DEFault Var`.